# no doctype found for this xml sitemap - how to fix?

Tags: xml, validation, xslt, sitemap, doctype

I have a sitemap in xml format transformed in html with xsl file... I have a warning while I go for validating sitemap: "no doctype found for this xml sitemap, check your syntax"

This is the only warning I get when try to validate my sitemap... how to fix?

http://www.alecos.it/sitemap.xml  <--- this is my xml sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="sitemap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/games.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_31032007.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_30012007.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_28082006.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_26012006.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_25102008.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_15072007.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_06062005.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary_04092010.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.alecos.it/diary.php</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  cut... cut...
</urlset>
```

http://www.alecos.it/sitemap.xsl  <--- this is my html/css document for my sitemap xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
  xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>SiteMap - Alecos Web Site By Alessandro Marinuzzi</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 68.5%;
  color: #333;
}
table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.sitemap tr.odd {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.sitemap tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddf4df;
}
.sitemap tbody tr:hover td, .sitemap tbody tr:hover td a {
  color: #060;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.intro p {
  color: #060;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #690;
}
table {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
thead th {
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #99cc99;
  border-top: 1px solid #99cc99;
}
tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1><a href="index.php" title="Alecos Web Site"><img src="gfx/Logo.png" alt="[Alecos WebSite SiteMap]" border="0"/></a></h1>
<div class="intro">
<p>Generated By <a href="http://www.alecos.it/">www.alecos.it</a>. Windows, Linux, Unix, MacOS(X) and Amiga programs, scripts, translations, articles and more...</p>
<p>This sitemap contains <xsl:value-of select="count(sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url)"/> URLs.</p>
</div>
<table class="sitemap" cellpadding="3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="80%">URL</th>
      <th width="10%">Priority</th>
      <th width="10%">Change Frequency</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:variable name="itemURL">
            <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <a href="{$itemURL}">
            <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(sitemap:priority*100,'%')"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(sitemap:changefreq, 1, 1),concat($lower, $upper),concat($upper, $lower)),substring(sitemap:changefreq, 2))"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried all ways but none does goal... Ideas? Tips? Tricks?

Google accepts my sitemap without error or warning but xml validators give me an error/warning... Thanks

Comment: How are you writing out the transformed result so that it's displayed in the browser? You can always change the output type to XML in the XSL as the output will still be HTML (just well formed HTML) that a browser should be able to parse. As @BoltClock mentions, however, it's really not required. Unless, of course you are talking about the <!DOCTYPE for html documents and are using the w3c validator. In which case, just amend the xls template to also write out the appropriate DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is an example how to generate the wanted DOCTYPE**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<html>
 <title>Some Title</title>
 <body>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**it copies the document "as-is" and generates the XHTML transitional doctype**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <title>Some Title</title>
   <body>
      <p>Hello, World!</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

Use of the following attributes of **[`xsl:output`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#output)**: `doctype-public` and `doctype-system` .

Answer (score 0):

sitemap.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
  xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output
  omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
  indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>SiteMap - Alecos Web Site By Alessandro Marinuzzi</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 68.5%;
  color: #333;
}
table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.sitemap tr.odd {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.sitemap tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddf4df;
}
.sitemap tbody tr:hover td, .sitemap tbody tr:hover td a {
  color: #060;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.intro p {
  color: #060;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #690;
}
table {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
thead th {
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #99cc99;
  border-top: 1px solid #99cc99;
}
tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1><a href="index.php" title="Alecos Web Site"><img src="gfx/Logo.png" alt="[Alecos WebSite SiteMap]" border="0"/></a></h1>
<div class="intro">
  <p>Generated By <a href="http://www.alecos.it/">www.alecos.it</a>. Windows, Linux, Unix, MacOS(X) and Amiga programs, scripts, translations, articles and more...</p>
  <p>This sitemap contains <xsl:value-of select="count(sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url)"/> URLs.</p>
</div>
<table class="sitemap" cellpadding="3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="80%">URL</th>
      <th width="10%">Priority</th>
      <th width="10%">Change Frequency</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:variable name="itemURL">
            <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <a href="{$itemURL}">
            <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(sitemap:priority*100,'%')"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(sitemap:changefreq, 1, 1),concat($lower, $upper),concat($upper, $lower)),substring(sitemap:changefreq, 2))"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Works great without errors or warnings and the sitemap.xml now has a correct doctype that makes it validated without problems. Use & share as you like! Thanks!

Comment: Too big, buddy. This isn't related to the initial question and to the correct answer -- you have some other error that you need to find and fix. Actually there are many errors here. Please, ask a new, separate question, but with small XML document and also specify the wanted result. It seems that you need to read a good XSLT/XPath book just to get to know the basics.

Comment: Oky this post is wrong... I can understand it by myself but since I know just a bit and not more xsl can you tell me how correct the code? Thanks. Maybe in the future I'll buy a book about xml/xsl but at the moment I need a fix for doctype not found... read my first post at the beginning (I asked in my first post how to fix the problem of doctype and this is the question for me, simple and clear). Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a "post" -- this is an answer -- that in fact contains a new question. Please, ask a new question as a ... question -- not as an answer. Your *question* is fully answered -- I have given a complete example how what you want to do is done. Please, start with small XML document and assure your transformation works. Why it doesn't work --Ask a question. Read a book, or otherwise it would be difficult for you to understand the answers.

Comment: Why should I open a new question? Look at the code that I edited now... at the moment works but I had to change the output from xml to html because I'm able to see only plain text instead of html and there is the old problem of doctype missing...

Comment: user1582059, It is appropriate to ask a new question, because your code has many errors, which *aren't*` directly related to the current question.

Comment: Right! I opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078640/problems-with-sitemap-xml-and-xsl-no-doctype-found-and-incorrect-syntax and I solved trying by myself. Now I have a doctype in my xml sitemap and is well validated! Thanks!